# h2o - Whats the difference between MOJO zip file and genmodel.jar file.

Tags: h2o

I have figured out how to download models as a MOJO, and how to use that to then make predictions onto new datasets that are in .csv format. I wanted to understand a little better how the .zip file of the model and the h2o-genmodel.jar files relate to each other. Here are my questions?

- 1.) What is the exact difference about what each of these are storing / doing.
- 2.) Is the genmodel.jar file specific to that model in question, or can it be executed against a different .zip MOJO model file?
- If I am going to be downloading off multiple models, does each one need its own genmodel.jar file, along with the .zip file of the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The .zip file is the model artifact and metadata itself.
The h2o-genmodel.jar is the execution runtime used to make predictions with the model.

2) The latest h2o-genmodel.jar can be used for all current and older mojo .zip models.

For MOJOs, you only need one current h2o-genmodel.jar.